# SAS: Rename a Macro Catalog

Tags: macros, sas, catalog

I want to store macros in a catalog.  Doing so allows many macros to be shared with just a single file, as well as introduces a degree of separation from the user.

To store my macro, I run a program such as

```
/* HelloWorld.sas */
libname pwd ".";              /* assign current directory */
option mstored sasmstore=pwd; /* set pwd as storage directory */ 

%macro HelloWorld() 
    / store source;           /* store compiled macro along with its source */
  data _null_;
    put "Hello, World!";
  run;
%mend;
```

This creates a `sasmacr.sas7bcat` file in the directory in which `HelloWorld.sas`lives.  I can then move that file to another directory, such as `C:\myMacros`and run the following program:

```
/* CallHelloWorld.sas */
libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';
option mstored sasmstore=myMacros;

%HelloWorld();
```

The macro `HelloWorld()` is called without error.

However, if I want to consider the `HelloWorld()` macro as part of a "HelloWorld" macro suite, I cannot simply change the catalog name in Windows Explorer from `sasmacr.sas7bcat` to `HelloWorld.sas7bcat`.  When I do this and try running `CallHelloWorld.sas` again (after closing and reopening SAS), the macro is not resolved.

```
1    /* CallHelloWorld.sas */
2    libname myMacros 'C:\myMacros';
NOTE: Libref MYMACROS was successfully assigned as follows:
      Engine:        V9
      Physical Name: C:\myMacros
3    option mstored sasmstore=myMacros;
4
5    %HelloWorld();
     -
     180
NOTE: The SAS System was unable to open the macro library referenced by the SASMSTORE = libref
      MYMACROS.
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro HELLOWORLD not resolved.

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

ERROR: Catalog MYMACROS.SASMACR does not exist.
NOTE: The SAS System was unable to open the macro library referenced by the SASMSTORE = libref
      MYMACROS.
ERROR: An error occurred during the execution of the %COPY statement.
```

How do I change the name of a catalog which contains macros so that those macros may be called in various programs?  Is it possible to name the catalog something different than `sasmacr` up front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can rename the catalog away from SASMACR and still use it directly.  However, you could use `PROC CATALOG` potentially to manage the `SASMACR` catalog.

What you'd want to do is, when you wanted to include a particular macro, copy it via `proc catalog` from its source location into your chosen `SASMSTORE` location.

Something like:

```
libname myMacros 'C:\temp';
libname pwd '.';

options mstored sasmstore=pwd;

proc catalog catalog=myMacros.HelloWorld;
  copy out=pwd.sasmacr;
run;
quit;


%HelloWorld();
```

Now - I would suggest this is probably overkill; there's really no reason to have separate macro catalogs this way.  If you like the idea of separately including files, you may want to consider Autocall macros (where you don't store them compiled, but store their source and compile-on-demand); really compiling a macro costs nearly nothing in SAS anyway.  But if using stored-compiled macros is what you like, this method is probably the best way to do it.

Of course, I think an easier way would be to leave the catalog `SASMACR.SAS7BCAT` and use the directory name to determine what it is, and then append librefs to your `sasmstore` option value.

Comment: I strongly contend that there is good reason to want macros in a uniquely named catalog. The crux is being able to share project specific macros with other people. A catalog appears to be the only container SAS recognizes.  Without a catalog, macros must exist as individual files at some point before loading. This risks loss, modification, etc. It limits control.  Further, a single catalog name becomes an issue when working on multiple projects with the same people. A person may have several `sasmacr` files, each corresponding to a different project. The solution is individual catalog names.

Comment: From the SAS: Certification Prep Guide, 4ed, Chapter 12, Section "Using Stored Compiled Macros", "Sasmacr is the only catalog in which compiled macros can be stored. You can create a catalog named Sasmacr in any SAS library. You should not rename this catalog or its entries."  Is it possible to store `sasmacr` itself in a catalog which may bear a unique name?

Comment: The solution is having several different _folders_, at least as far as I can tell SAS would have you do. Then libname to each folder. That is the answer to your second comment: put each in a unique folder then libname to each folder which is effectively what you describe for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 3):

At least on Unix with SAS 9.4 you can use the SASAUTOS option to point at a FILEREF that uses the ZIP engine so that all of the macro definitions are stored in a single ZIP file.

The one "trick" is that you need to change the names of the member files in the ZIP file. Normally on unix SASAUTOS requires that the source files are named using the macro name in lowercase with a `.sas` extension (`helloworld.sas`).  But for SASAUTOS to work with a ZIP file the members should be named using the macro name in uppercase with NO extension (`HELLOWORLD`).

```
filename mymacros zip '~/mymacros.zip';
options insert=(sasautos=(mymacros)) ;
```

**EDIT**

Unfortunately this method causes SAS to generate ERROR: messages when the macro source file is not found in the ZIP file, even if it is ultimately found in another file in the SASAUTOS option search path.

Comment: Something like this works on Windows.  One may issue

`filename mymacros zip 'C:\myMacros\HelloWorld.zip' fileext lowcase_memname;`

`options SASAUTOS = (mymacros sasautos);`

However, you are unable to run the `filename` statement more than once, as indicated here: http://support.sas.com/kb/31/540.html

I changed the `options` statement based on http://support.sas.com/kb/44/791.html

And the FILENAME ZIP has options given here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1dn0f61yfyzton1l2ngsa1clllr.htm

Comment: That's pretty nifty!  Nice way to share a macro library, or perhaps store alternate macro libraries and point to them.  And if you can lock down the .zip file with a write password, would be an easy way to avoid accidental changes.  This seems like a nice way to meet the goal of storing macros in a single file.

Comment: Thanks for the hints on the zip engine options. The "bug" with locking filerefs used in SASAUTOS has been there for a long time. When using directories to store autocall macros I always use the physical path rather than the fileref in the SASAUTOS because of this,  But to take advantage of the ZIP engine you will need to use a fileref.  If you want to switch which sets of macros to reference in a single session then you will need to create unique filerefs rather than trying to reuse a common fileref to point to different ZIP files.

Comment: @Tom, Wondering if you think that the error message when the macro source file is not found in the zip file is worthy of a bug report to SAS, and if maybe you sent it in already?

Comment: @Quentin I think I did submit a query to SAS, but I don't remember if they put into things to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From DATA_NULL_ I have received the answer to how to use to existing catalogs with different names. Use the CATNAME statement.  So if you have catalogs TEST.CAT1 and TEST.CAT2 you can use the CATNAME statement to make TEST.SASMACR be the concatenation of the two macros.

```
CATNAME test.sasmacr
  (test.cat1 (ACCESS=READONLY)
   test.cat2 (ACCESS=READONLY)
  )
;
```

You can now point the SASMSTORE option the the TEST libref.

```
option mstored sasmstore=test;
```

Here is an example of how you might create such separate catalogs using `PROC CATALOG` to copy members that have been compiled into a `SASMACR` catalog into catalogs with different names.

```
libname templib '~/test/cat1';
libname permlib '~/test';
options mstored sasmstore=templib;

%macro HelloWorld1() / store source;
  data _null_;
    put "Hello, World! &sysmacroname";
  run;
%mend;

%macro HelloWorld2() / store source;
  data _null_;
    put "Hello, World! &sysmacroname";
  run;
%mend;

proc catalog cat=templib.sasmacr ;
   copy out=permlib.cat1;
      select helloworld1 /et=macro;
   run;
   copy out=permlib.cat2;
      select helloworld2 /et=macro;
   run;
quit;
```

Now use the `CATNAME` command to chain the catalogs together.

```
options mstored sasmstore=permlib;
CATNAME permlib.sasmacr
  (permlib.cat1 (ACCESS=READONLY)
   permlib.cat2 (ACCESS=READONLY)
);

%helloworld1;
%helloworld2;
```